# how to manage day light saving on azure

Tags: azure, testing

how to schedule web jobs with day light saving. we have schedule web jobs on azure to run service(15:00 UTC and 8:00 MST) but when day light saving start it run 9 AM MST. could you please tell me, how to manage fix it.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is hosted on Azure Virtual Machines, you have complete access to the VM so you can configure the time zone to whatever you want.

If your app is hosted on Azure Cloud Services, it is possible to write a startup script that calls the tzutil utility to change the time zone; however [this isn’t recommended and can apparently lead to instability](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2013/07/29/manage-timezone-for-applications-on-windows-azure/).

If your app is hosted as a Web App on the Azure App Service (formerly known as Azure Websites), until recently you were completely out of luck. However, there is now an easy and supported way to change the time zone for your w3wp process (and any processes it spawns):
All you need to do is add an [Application Setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure) (via the portal or the management APIs) called WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE and set that to the name of the time zone as defined in the Windows Registry under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Nt\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\ (for example, “AUS Eastern Standard Time”).

Refer: [Add DST timezone support for webjobs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1783)